# React bootstrap autosuggest highlights multiple items

Tags: react-bootstrap, autosuggest

I'm using [React Bootstrap Autosuggest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-autosuggest/) really nice and complete tool, but I have a problem with my ItemAdapter, I want to search from different properties in my item: Name, City, State, Country.

It works fine until you enter the full name from a city state or country, for example it will select all the items where country = "España", selecting the item when it's the only one is fine for me, but not when there are multiple items with the same country or state.

Could someone please help me?

[image]

This is my item adapter:

```
class RepoAdapter extends ItemAdapter {
    getTextRepresentations(item) {
        return [
            (item.Name || "").toLowerCase(),
            (item.City || "").toLowerCase(),
            (item.State || "").toLowerCase(),
            (item.Country || "").toLowerCase(),
            (item.CelebratedBy || "").toLowerCase()];
      }
    sortItems(items) {
      return items; 
    }
    renderItem(item) {
      return <div>
            <h4>{item.Name}</h4>
            <div>
                {item.Address1 ? item.Address1 + ", " : ""} 
                {item.City ? item.City + ", " : ""} 
                {item.State ? item.State + ", " : ""} 
                {item.Country} 
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

(BTW I tried using the suggested rbs-autosuggest tag, but it didn't allow me since it would be a new tag and I don't have enough "reputation" in SO).

Answer (score 0):

My partial solution was to concatenate the fields in a single string, this is not perfect since I can't add multiple words in different orders, if I later come back and solve this in a better way I'll update my answer.

```
getTextRepresentations(item) {
    return [
        (item.Name || "").toLowerCase() +
        (item.City || "").toLowerCase() +
        (item.State || "").toLowerCase() +
        (item.Country || "").toLowerCase() +
        (item.CelebratedBy || "").toLowerCase()];
  }
```